# How to Differentiate Two Integration Processes?

Tags: apex

I am working on an integration scenario where records are loaded into an custom object and  The custom object is loaded twice due to the fact that data resides in two separate systems.

- First customer information is loaded. Assume field1, field2 and
  field3 is updated.
- Second financial information is loaded. This is when the trigger
  should fire and  do some calculations/aggregations. In this case
  field4 is updated.

I don't want the trigger should fire in first case so I am comparing old values and new values of field4 and skipping the triiger logic but in few cases, the old value and new value of field4 is same when I do the second load. It means old value is 10000 and new value is also 10000. It is an update but same value. Since the updated value is same as old value, The check I put is skipping the trigger logic which I don't want.

Is there anyway to skip the triiger logic during first load and just run it during the second load. I thought of creating a flag field and set it to true during first load and check for it in trigger. If true then skip the trigger.

I would like to know If there is any other way to solve this issue without introducing another field.

Comment: does both the updates happen thru the same api / integration user ? or does each source system use its own dedicated user to update in salesforce ?

Comment: The integration happens via same user id.

Comment: does the first system always do an insert of a new record, or is that an update already?

Comment: The integration process uses upsert operation in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely only fire your trigger when field4 changes; this can be accomplished via record filtering. You may want to look into the [Selector library](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) to help, or you can accomplish it in your code fairly simply:

```
public static List<MyObject__c> hasField4Changed(List<MyObject__c> newRecords,
    Map<Id, MyObject__c> oldMap)
{
    List<MyObject__c> records = new List<MyObject__c>();
    for (MyObject__c newRecord : newRecords)
    {
        MyObject__c oldRecord = oldMap.get(newRecord.Id);
        if (oldRecord != null && oldRecord.Field4__c != newRecord.Field4__c)
        {
            records.add(newRecord);
        }
    }
    return records;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now that I understand your question better, it seems the ideal course of action would be to have a dedicated `User` for each integration and when the `User` for your second integration is the running user, assume the second integration is running.

I would recommend something like the following:

```
public class MyIntegrationServices
{
    @TestVisible static String INTEGRATION_USERNAME = 'someuser@someorg.com`;
    public Boolean isRunningIntegration()
    {
        return UserInfo.getUsername() == INTEGRATION_USERNAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, I can't put the above logic because in my case, the old and new values are same during the load. During the second load, The trigger needs to run anytime there is an update regardless of the old and new values.

Comment: This logic will return no records during insert because your oldMap won't have any values. It will only return records whose `Field4` value has changed during an update. You said that field was being updated...

Comment: OK. Let me explain with an example. In my case, the old value 1000 and new value is also 1000. If I put the above logic, it will skip trigger logic because old and new values are same. I always want to run the trigger logic during second load and want to skip only during first load.

Comment: You need some way to differentiate the options. You may be able to detect running user if your integrations each have a separate one dedicated to them specifically.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I am thinking. Either use separate user ids for loading OR  create a field and set to true during second load so the logic is triggered and reset to false after the calculation is done.